# Approximating sums of series and finding the largest error expected

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Here is the sum: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{e^k}$. How do I do the following:

a) approximate the sum of the series using $s_{6}$. (with calculator)

b) find the largest error expected in the approximation

I am not sure how to do this with my calculator, or how to find the largest error ... Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: May be, you could fix the expression : I suppose that you mean $\sum_{\color{red}{k}=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{e^k}$

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way
to get the error
in truncating the sum
after any given
number of terms.

Since
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^k
=\dfrac{x}{1-x}
$
and
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kx^k
=\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}
$,
if $m \ge 1$,
the sum of the series
with the first $m$
terms removed is

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty} kx^k
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (k+m)x^{k+m}\\
&=x^m\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (k+m)x^{k}\\
&=x^m\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kx^{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} mx^{k}\right)\\
&=x^m\left(\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}+\dfrac{mx}{1-x}\right)\\
&=x^m\left(\dfrac{x+mx(1-x)}{(1-x)^2}\right)\\
&=x^{m+1}\dfrac{1+m(1-x)}{(1-x)^2}\\
&=x^{m+1}\dfrac{m+1-mx}{(1-x)^2}\\
\end{array}
$

Putting $x = \dfrac1{e}$,
$\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{k}{e^k}
=\dfrac{1+m(1-1/e)}{e^{m+1}(1-1/e)^2}
$.